# Understanding だったって

Tags: grammar

> 「ちっちゃい頃、おおきくなったらけっこんしようねって言ったこととか」
>
> 「えっ」
>
> 思わず変な声を出してしまったレーナを見返して。
>
> アネットは不意に、にまーっと笑った。
>
> 久しぶりに見る、屈託のない表情だった。
>
> 「なんてね。ほんとだけど。……シンってば昔っからそういうとこ鈍いから。ずっと同じ部隊**だったって**女の子もいるし、グイグイ押してかないと負けちゃうわよ？」
>
> 「あっ、アネット……!?」

86─エイティシックス─Ep.4　─アンダー・プレッシャー─
安里アサト

Why is だったって used there instead of just だった? Grammatically, だった can take 女の子 but だったって can’t, if the meaning is "there are girls in the same troop". Or does the bold だったって mean "even if"? But this meaning doesn’t make much sense in this context.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, って is a colloquial quotation marker similar to という, which turns the preceding words into an adjective phrase that describes the noun that follows it. In other words,

ずっと同じ部隊だった**って**女の子もいるし

is similar to:

ずっと同じ部隊だった**という**女の子もいるし

Let's look at the meaning now.

ずっと同じ部隊だった**って**: that have been in the unit for a long time

女の子もいるし: There are also girls

ずっと同じ部隊だった**って**女の子もいるし: There are also girls that have been in the same unit for a long time.

See [って (Colloquial Topic Marker)](https://wildnihongo.com/grammar/tte-colloquial-topic-marker/)

Comment: Thank you. So can we omit the って? I often see the noun+だった+noun construction.

Comment: @chinoalpha - When you say ずっと同じ部隊だった女の子, you know for a fact that the girls have been in the same troop. It’s to say *the girls who have been …*. ずっと同じ部隊だったって女の子 is more like *the girls who claim to have been …* or *the girls I hear have been …*. Either way, the part before って is quoted.